# Why laravel 5.1 form class not found?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am using **laravel 5.1**. I am working with form but browser is showing an error like this.

> FatalErrorException in 44a7f556a7d1beef3d09ba2ba2e3c7f0 line 7:
>     Class 'form' not found.

I have already tried to solve this problem by these commands:

```
1) composer require illuminate/html
2) update in app file provide and aliases section
```

I don't know why happening this. Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your `composer.json` file, add this line

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
}
```

You need to run `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` as any changes to your `composer.json` file means it needs to be reloaded.

In your `config/app.php`

```
 'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of `config/app.php`:

```
 'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Also you might want to check out Laravel Collective [Forms & HTML](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html)

You'd need to use:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
    //
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: laravel collective uses psr-4 autoloading, so it is not necessary to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Milan:  If you have a new class somewhere in your project it will not be loaded unless it is included in autoload_classmap (hence you have to execute composer dump-autoload)